# Got a new server and desktop - Cant get QB RDS to connect anymore

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I use Quickbooks RDS to connect an Access Database to Quickbooks.  Everything has been going fine but we recently upgraded our entire network and now I get error messages when trying to establish a connection from the RDS client to server.  The error is "Public Key Exchange Error - object already exists".  I was just wondering why this is all of a sudden happening.  I am assuming it's a permissions thing based on what I've read.  I've gone into the MachineKeys file folder and tried to change the permissions to allow all but that didnt fix it.  I also disabled the windows firewall, added exceptions for the port it requires, and disabled the antivirus.  My QB file is stored on my network drive but I use one of the workstations as the RDS Server.  Has anyone encountered this before?  I am using QB2012 and RDS6.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This site is for programming questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and it sounds like your question might be better suited to another site, perhaps http://superuser.com/?

Comment: There used to be a site (Intuit IDN Forums) but they said they moved all of their stuff here.

Comment: The IDN Forums for Intuit product related questions are still fine, the technical questions for IPP are answered here.